# How to handle returning list

Tags: c#

I'm wondering how I should handle return of reference of list from another class? I want to pick the contents of the list from the calling method?

A simplified method that I use to fill a list with numbers and then return the reference of the list

```
public List<int> Shuffle()
{
    code....
    return nameOfList;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fine.

The list will be disposed of correctly once the reference in the calling code falls out of scope.

To use the list all you need to do is:

```
List<int> myList = otherObject.Shuffle();
```

You need to create the list in your method:

```
public List<int> Shuffle()
{
    List<int> nameOfList = new List<int>();
    code....
    return nameOfList;
}
```

Comment: But I'm not sure how to use it and pick the contents from the calling method?

Comment: I have already created the list in the beginning of the class!?

Comment: But it's perhaps better to create it inside the method if I want to create a new list with new content, because I guess the current list will be erased?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to create the List, fill it and return it, or you can pass it as a parameter, and fill it.

**OPTION A**

```
public List<int> Shuffle()
{
    nameOfList = new List<int>();
    code....
    return nameOfList;
}
```

**OPTION B**

```
Call:
Shuffle(ref myList);

Implementation:
public List<int> Shuffle(ref List<int> myList) 
{
    // work on myList
}
```

Comment: OK, Correct me if I'm wrong but am I returning the list or just a reference with my code? I just want to call this method once and fill the list with some numbers and then in the calling method pick the contents, it's the last part I'm not sure how to handle?

Comment: What do you mean by "pick the contents"?

Comment: Your passig a reference to the list, but in order to pass the list var by reference you may use: public List<int> Shuffle(ref List<int> myList) {...} and pass the List like: Shuffle(ref myList). in this case you will get all changes done to the list inside the Shuffle routine.

Comment: Pick the contents, i mean to use the numbers and each position of the list. The list has been filled with random numbers in the method Shuffle.

Comment: 3D: Depending on what you need you can either pass the List with the Contents, work on it and return it back (Option B), or create a new one which you return back at the end(Option A)

Comment: If the List is filled in side the Shuffle methode option A would be enough for your needs.

Comment: It was this I was looking for: List<int> myList = otherObject.Shuffle(); But thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

List is a reference type, so a reference will always be returned, even if you instantiate the list in your called method.